# TypeError in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was working on the assignment and trying to get the mongoose code we used in the tutorial today working.
I'm getting an error though and I'm not sure why.

index.js:

---

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var Rooms2406;

var setupRoomDB = function () {
    var roomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    roomExits: [String]
    });
    Rooms2406 = mongoose.model("Rooms2406", roomSchema);
}
db.once('open', setupRoomDB);


var addRooms = function(){
    /*to do a check each time a room is added*/

    var saveCallbackFunc = function(err, theRoom){
            var status;
            if(err)
                status = 'fail';
            else{
                status = 'sucess';
            }
            console.log(status);
    }

    /*go through the rooms and add each one*/
    debugger;

    /*THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS*/
    var bridge = new Rooms2406({
    title: "Bridge",
    description: "blah",
    roomExits: ['sickbay']});

    debugger;

    var engineering = new Rooms2406({
    title: "Engineering",
    description: "blah.",
    roomExits: ['sickbay']
    });  

    var sickbay = new Rooms2406({
    title: "Sickbay",
    description: "blah",
    roomExits: ['engineering','bridge']
    });

    var secret= new Rooms2406({
    title: "Secret Room",
    description: "blah",
    roomExits: ['engineering', 'sickbay', 'bridge']
    });

    var TheVoid= new Rooms2406({
    title: "The Void",
    description: "blah.",
    roomExits: ['TheVoid']
    });

    /*saving each room*/
    bridge.save(saveCallbackFunc);
    engineering.save(saveCallbackFunc);
    sickbay.save(saveCallbackFunc);
    secret.save(saveCallbackFunc);   
    TheVoid.save(saveCallbackFunc);
```

---

Then in the start() function I call addRooms() to save the rooms to the database.

```
function start(req, res) {
/*add rooms to mongodb*/
    addRooms();
    var player = req.body.player;
    // Sanitize the player name as it may be displayed
    req.session.player = sanitize(player).escape();
    req.session.currentRoom = "bridge"; // We start on the bridge
    res.redirect("/game")
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

---

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at addRooms (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/routes/index.js:45:15)
    at start (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/routes/index.js:100:2)
    at callbacks (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at next (/home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:312:9)
    at /home/student/a4/adventure-ajax-demo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:336:9
```

---

I have narrowed this down to be an issue with

```
var bridge = new Rooms2406 ({etc...});
```

I don't understand what is wrong here, its like it doesn't know what Rooms2406 is but I have defined it already.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't look like `setupRoomDB` is called: the `open` event on `db` isn't emitted. How do you create the connection to the MongoDB database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that,setupRoomDb function is not being called, which is responsible for initializing the variable room2406 with the model, as it stands the variable is undefined and hence when you call the addRooms function, the above mentioned errors occur.

The reason why setupRoomDB is not being called is simply because the database open event is never fired, as you have not set up a database connection, use mongoose.connect to connect to your database and it will solve your error.

updated code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDatabase')//use appropriate database here.
var db = mongoose.connection;
var Rooms2406;

var setupRoomDB = function () {
    var roomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    roomExits: [String]
    });
    Rooms2406 = mongoose.model("Rooms2406", roomSchema);
}
db.once('open', setupRoomDB);
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. But How would I go about doing that so that it is only defined once in mongodb?

Comment: I'm not sure you've connected to your database, 
include the following line
mongoose.connect('path to your db');
something like mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/yourdbname');